# Getting user's votes from query

Tags: python, django

I have a poll app with three models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_votes     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question    = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice      = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Voting(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice  = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answered_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The `Question` model is where all questions are stored, the `Choice` model is where all choices to those questions are stored, and the `Voting` model is where user votes are stored and which choice they chose. I need to make a query where I check if the logged in user answered the question and if they did which choice they picked. How do I make this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we'll get the relevant QuerySet - of all `Voting` instances associated with both the logged-in user and the question under consideration (whose corresponding object I've arbitrarily called `Question`):

```
votes = Voting.objects.filter(user=request.user, choice__question==Question)
```

This is a QuerySet object, and may represent an empty set of results. To find out if any instances exist - that is, that the user voted on the question - just check:

```
votes.exists()
```

And if it does, which choice they selected (assuming they can only ever select one at most) can be extracted from:

```
votes.choice[0].choice
```

(that is if you want the value of the actual `choice` field).

(I also encourage you to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/, if you haven't already. All the Django documentation is fantastic imo, both for overviews and API reference.)

Comment: Hmm when I do `votes.choice` I get an error that says:  `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'choice'`

Comment: @user2896120 - oops, sorry I got confused. That property access only works on an actual object from your model, not a QuerySet. Since we already know by this point that such an object exists, and I presume there would never be more than one (ie. a user can never select more than one choice for the same question), then you should be able to just do `votes[0].choice`. Let me know if this works, and if it does I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Hmm, when I do that I get: `<Choice: Choice object (2)>`

Comment: sorry, missed the field access: `votes[0].choice.choice` (or possibly `votes[0].choice.pk` if you just want the database id - which is often more useful)

Comment: great, thanks - sorry for the hiccups earlier, I'll update the answer